# Battery in off-mode. How does it gain it's energy automatically?

Tags: everyday-life, batteries

How does battery becomes charged for a very little amount when it is in switched off mode. I have observed this phenomena in Mobile phone, Digital camera battery and in daily life inverter also. May be it is a duplicate question. Please give me the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Batteries are chemical engines; when a battery is nearly depleted, sometimes the chemical waste products (gas) can build up.   When that gas pressure is high, the chemical reaction (which creates MORE gas) is inhibited by the gas back-pressure.
So, if one removes the load, and waits a while, the gas will leak away
and the battery seems to 'recover' slightly.   It still is a near-dead battery,
but operates more efficiently after its rest.

Answer (score 0):

Within the power supplies there are capacitors which are still charged when the mains power supply is switched off.
The red/green light etc stays on because current is still flowing in the circuit as the capacitors discharge.

If the capacitors staying charged after the mains poser supply is turned off then [bleeder resistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleeder_resistor) are introduced into the circuitry to reduce the time over which the capacitors discharge.